# How to specify configuration order among Gradle sub-projects?

Tags: gradle

`settings.gradle` is:

```
rootProject.name = 'snth'

include 'snth-proto-definition'
include 'snth-server'
include 'snth-client-guice'
```

`snth-server/build.gradle` has:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir "${project(':snth-proto-definition').protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/server/java"
    }
  }
}
```

`snth-client/build.gradle` has:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir "${project(':snth-proto-definition').protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/client/java"
    }
  }
}
```

But while `snth-server-guice/build.gradle` gets processed fine, `snth-client-guice/build.gradle` errors with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'snth/snth-client-guice/build.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':snth-client-guice'.
> Could not find property 'protobuf' on project ':snth-proto-definition'.
```

How can I ensure that `project(':snth-proto-definition').protobuf` is defined before it's used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Configuration time dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sub:configuration_time_dependencies) indicates use of `evaluationDependsOn` would allow finer-grained control of the configuration order of sub-modules. For example:

```
evaluationDependsOn(':snth-proto-definition')
```